# OnElementChanged(...) not getting the new value of property

Tags: android, xamarin, binding, xamarin.forms

I have a a map that displays a route between points. This is working but now **I want to pass some color values from PCL**. I have a custom renderer for android and a class acting as bridge between PCL and Android with bindable properties in it.
(For the map I use the PCL implementation and extends it with the custom renderer)

For now I got:

(android : CustomMapRenderer)

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomMap), typeof(MapOverlay.Droid.CustomMapRenderer))]
namespace MapOverlay.Droid
{
public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer , ICustomMap
{
    List<Position> routeCoordinates;
    Int32 RouteColor;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            // Unsubscribe
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
            routeCoordinates = formsMap.RouteCoordinates;
            Control.GetMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (this.Element == null || this.Control == null)
            return;
       
        if (e.PropertyName == "VisibleRegion")
        {
            var polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
            polylineOptions.InvokeColor(0x66FF0000);

            foreach (var position in routeCoordinates)
            {
                polylineOptions.Add(new LatLng(position.Latitude, position.Longitude));
            }

            NativeMap.AddPolyline(polylineOptions);
        }
    }

    public void working()
    {
        Log.Debug("xxxx", "WORKING");
    }
  }
}
```

Now the class acting as bridge from PCL to Android
(PCL : CustomMap)

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{

public class CustomMap : Map
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty RouteCoordinatesProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create<CustomMap, List<Position>>(p => p.RouteCoordinates, new List<Position>());
    
    public static readonly BindableProperty RouteColorProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create<CustomMap, int>(p => p.RouteColor, 0x66FF0000);

    //Property used to add points to the map. Then polyline utility will draw a line beteween thoses points
    public List<Position> RouteCoordinates
    {
        get { return (List<Position>)base.GetValue(RouteCoordinatesProperty); }
        set {
            base.SetValue(RouteCoordinatesProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public Int32 RouteColor
    {
        get { return (Int32)base.GetValue(RouteColorProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(RouteColorProperty, value); }
    }


    public CustomMap()
    {
        RouteCoordinates = new List<Position>();
    }

   }
}
```

So as you can see I added an `Int32 RouteColor` variable which should be used in the CustomMapRenderer to change the color of the displayed route.

But when I change this value in my PCL code like so:

```
mCustomMap.RouteColor = 0x22AA0000;
```

**It triggers an OnElementPropertyChanged response but not an OnElementChanged event.**
So I can't get the changed value. I only know that it DID changed (with the OnElementPropertyChanged).

If someone knows how to bypass this phenomena... All suggestions are welcome.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use e.PropertyName to find which property changed

Comment: @G.Sharada I know that the property has change. Its the value that I want :-)

Comment: And you get the value by using `Element.RouteColor` - `Element` represents the forms element, while `Control` represents the native control.

Comment: @G.Sharada Interesting ! I do have an "Element" member variable. But I don't have "Element.RouteColor" accessible...

Comment: try casting to `CustomMap`

Comment: @G.Sharada It woooorrkkss ! Thank you very much !! If you add this as an answer i'll choose it as the working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Element` represents the forms element, which in this case should be `CustomMap`. You can use it to retrieve the property values.

**For e.g.:**

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

    if (this.Element == null || this.Control == null)
        return;
    ....
    //if RouteColor is the property that changed
    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(CustomMap.RouteColor))
    {
        //get new value
        var newColor = (Element as CustomMap)?.RouteColor;

        //and, update native control
        ....
```